# Q: Can I access the drive on a Power Macintosh 7200/75 as an external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, powerpc

I was recently given an older Power Macintosh 7200/75 that was owned by a family member, with the task of trying to access it to see what is on the hard drive.  It's just the base machine, no keyboard, mouse or monitor.

Is it possible for me to somehow connect this to my MacBook Air and then open the drive like it’s an external drive?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The PowerMac 7200 should an Ethernet port, so if you have the relevant adaptor for your MacBook Air (either Thunderbolt or USB), you can connect the two.

You'll then have to Start sharing in the File Sharing Control Panel on the PowerMac, and then if I remember correctly, set up Users or guest as you desire. Then you'll have to select the folders or disks you want to share, and under File > Get Info > Sharing, you can share that resource.

But this will entail having a mouse, keyboard and monitor. You may be able to source some of these cheaply in tech junk shops or ebay.

Comment: The ethernet port on that was an AAUI, and requires an adapter to then plug into an RJ-45 ethernet cable, back when there were other common types of ethernet, the most common being coax cable of various sizes. Eventually Apple saw the light and gave up on AAUI and went with the standard (RJ-45) ethernet jack.

Comment: @SteveChambers I've come up with Google images showing both AAUI and RJ-45 for this model. EveryMac says "2: Both AAUI-15 and 10-base-T".

Comment: You are correct sir, blame my faulty memory!! ;-)

Comment: @SteveChambers No probs. I used to have a 7600. I put in a PCI Ethernet card, for 100 T, and had a 4Gb (wow!) hard drive out of a Compaq server. I snaffled loads of RAM for its *8* slots. Good times.

Comment: I was looking up SCSI/USB adaptors this morning on eBay after I saw this post. People are asking $£€ 300 for them & they're usually some kind of printer adaptor, rather than HD. It's been so long since I used this stuff… I remember wiring an office for AppleTalk, back in the day. We thought we were bleeding-edge when we got a 14.4 modem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, haven't seen one of those in a while. Nice Mac for the time but hopelessly outdated these days, unless you need access to some classic (System 7, 8 9) MacOS for, well... *reasons.*

These old Macs are not going to yield to much in the way if all you have is a new Mac and the CPU itself.

The internal drive is SCSI making getting data off of it a bit problematic.

Your best bet might be trying to find an external drive case that supports SCSI drives with a USB case. Do these even exist anymore? New ones, possible, maybe, not sure. Used ones, more likely on eBay and such.

Failing that you may have to source a keyboard, mouse and monitor to investigate further.

If there is a Mac user group in your area someone there might be willing to assist you with the necessary equipment (loan/rent) or get the data off the drive for you.